# SQLitePCL для UWP

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

Делаю приложение под UWP, и решил использовать SQLite for UWP в качестве БД. Для работы с БД подключил SQLitePCL расширение. На запрос

```
using (var statement = con.Prepare("SELECT id, question, answer, answertrue FROM quest WHERE id=1"))
```

выскакивает ошибка, что таблицы `quest` не существует, и приложение закрывается. БД делаю с помощью `SqliteBrowser`. У меня вопрос: я допустил ошибку в запросе, или SQLitePCL не работает в UWP?

Comment: Так работало вроде. Вот [статья по ссылке](https://habrahabr.ru/post/265303/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в БД. Пересоздал с помощью SQLite Expert Personal и все заработало.

Comment: Тогда примите свой ответ как правильный, тот, что Вы приняли ответом не является

Comment: Вчера уже хотел, но пишет что могу принять свой ответ только завтра. Извините